# profile.html not displaying in this angular chat app with firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I was going through a chatapp tutorial and it said that when I redirect to http://localhost:4000/#/profile, I should be able to specify a display name for our user, submit the form and it should persist when we refresh the page. The issue is, nothing appears when I go there, just a white screen. Am I missing a semi colon or something?

Profile state in app.js

```
.state('profile', {
    url: '/profile',
    controller: 'ProfileCtrl as profileCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'Users/profile.html',
    resolve: {
      auth: function($state, Users, Auth) {
        return Auth.$requireAuth().catch(function(){
          $state.go('home');
        });
      },

      profile: function(Users, Auth){
        return Auth.$requireAuth().then(function(auth){
          return Users.getProfile(auth.uid).$loaded();
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

profile.controller.js

```
angular.module('chatApp')
  .controller('ProfileCtrl', function($state, md5, auth, profile){

    var profileCtrl = this;

    profileCtrl.profile = profile;

    profileCtrl.updateProfile = function(){
      profileCtrl.profile.emailHash = md5.createHash(auth.password.email);
      profileCtrl.profile.$save();
    }
  });
```

users.service.js

```
angular.module('chatApp')
  .factory('Users', function($firebaseArray, $firebaseObject, FirebaseUrl){

    var usersRef = new Firebase(FirebaseUrl+'users');

    var users = firebaseArray(usersRef);

    var Users = {
      getProfile: function(uid){
        return $firebaseObject(usersRef.child(uid));
      },

      getDisplayName: function(uid){
        return users.$getRecord(uid).displayName;
      },

      getGravatar: function(uid){
        return '//www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + users.$getRecord(uid).emailHash;
      },

      all: users
    };

    return Users;
  });
```

profile.html

```
<div class="page-wrapper">

  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Edit Profile</h1>
  </div>

  <form ng-submit="profileCtrl.updateProfile()">
    <p ng-hide="profileCtrl.profile.displayName">
      You'll need a display name before you can start chatting.
    </p>

    <div class="input-group">
      <input required type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Display Name" ng-model="profileCtrl.profile.displayName">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Set Display Name">
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is causing you're problem, but you're missing a `$` before `firebaseArray` in `var users = firebaseArray(usersRef);`

Comment: Fixed it! thanks aha I didn't see that! So how do you know when to use the $?

Comment: Was the missing `$` causing your problem? If so, I'll vote to close as a typo.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yep I was missing the $